# Django avoiding infinite save() loop, with ImageField saved using custom model method

Tags: python, django, database

I want to make my model call `save_image()` everytime user creates new Post model. 
I tried to override save() method, but it causes infinite loop (because `save_image()` calls `self.image.save()`. ). 
I tried disabling signals, but they did nothing. 
I wanted to add something like `@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)` for the save_image, and remove override of save() (I don't even know if it will solve problem with infinite loop).
The main problem here is that, save_post() MUST be called after standard save (because it needs Post.pk, Post.video). If you have any ideas, please help me.

Here's my code:

```
class Post(BaseModel):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     # Other fields
     video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos/', default='defaults/video.mp4')
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images', default='defaults/post_image.png')

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
         self.save_image()

     @receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
     def save_image(self):
         # Setting self.image to some frame of Video
         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video.path)
         video_length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
         if cap.isOpened() and video_length > 0:
             success, image = cap.read()
             if success:
                 rescaled = (255.0 / image.max() * (image - image.min())).astype(np.uint8)
                 PILimg = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
                 filename = "postimage"+str(self.pk)+".png"
                 f = BytesIO()
                 try:
                     PILimg.save(f, format='png')
                     s = f.getvalue()

                     self.image.save(filename, ContentFile(s))

                 finally:
                     f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
I had to add `save=False` to `self.image.save(filename, ContentFile(s))`. If you had similiar issue, you may also want to save whole model again (calling `super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` again).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.. I was creating a Reservation Confirmation pdf object by catching a post_save signal from Reservation model and ended up in an infinite loop when saving the pdf.

Below is the correct version of the code. The bug was in the last line which previously was:

**self.saved_file.save(File(file))**

```
class ReservationConfrimation(models.Model):
    reservation = models.OneToOneField(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    saved_file = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to="confirmations/")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self._create_pdf(self.reservation)

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def _create_pdf(self, reservation):
    # buffer = io.BytesIO()

    file = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(file, pagesize=letter, bottomup=1, verbosity=0)
    # w,h = letter
    c.line(0, 700, 612, 700)
    c.line(0, 100, 612, 100)
    c.drawString(306, 690, f"RESERVATION: {reservation.reservation_number}")
    c.save()
    file.name = f"{reservation.reservation_number}.pdf"

    self.saved_file = File(file)
```